# Finding maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

There are two positive integers $m$ and $n$. Let $$f(x)=\int_1^x {(t-a)^{2n}(t-b)^{2m+1}}dt, a\neq b$$
I need to find whether $f(x)$ is maximum/minimum at $x=a,b$.

**My Approach:**
I differentiated $f(x)$ with respect to $x$.
$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}{(\int_1^x {(t-a)^{2n}(t-b)^{2m+1}}dt)}$$
By Newton-Leibniz formula,
$$f'(x)=\big[(x-1)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}\big]\frac{dx}{dx}-\big[ (1-a)^{2n}(1-b)^{2m+1} \big]\frac{d}{dx}{(1)}$$
Thus, $f'(x)=(x-a)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}$.
For critical points, $f'(x)=0$,
$$0=(x-a)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}$$
So, $x=a$ and $x=b$ are critical points.
$$f''(x)=(x-b)^{2m+1}\frac{d(x-a)^{2n}}{dx}+(x-a)^{2n}\frac{d(x-b)^{2m+1}}{dx}$$
$$f''(x)=\big[ (x-b)^{2m+1}(2n)(x-a)^{2n-1} \big]+\big[ (x-a)^{2n}(2m+1)(x-b)^{2m} \big]$$
From here one can easily deduce that $f''(x)\geq0$. Now, if I put the value of $x=a$ or $x=b$, I'll get $f''(x)=0$ which gives that the function $f(x)$ has inflexion at $x=a$ and $x=b$. So where am I going wrong because the answer given in my book is that $x=b$ is a point of local minimum.

Comment: $f''(x)=0$ doesn't imply that its a zone of inflection. E.g. $f(x)=x^4$ at $x=0$ is a minimum, but has this property.

Comment: @JohnDoe but http://clas.sa.ucsb.edu/staff/lee/Inflection%20Points.htm says that at inflection point $f''(x)=0$.

Comment: Your solution is fine up to where you find the critical values. To classify them, use the First Derivative Test and make use of the fact that $2n$ is an even number while $2m+1$ is odd.

Comment: Yes, inflection point $\Rightarrow$ $f''(x)=0$, but $f''(x)=0$ $\nRightarrow$ inflection point. Essentially, $f''(x)=0$ is not very useful in classifying a stationary point.

Comment: @Ryan can you elaborate your comment, please.

Comment: @JohnDoe okay, I did not know that that converse is not true. Thanks. But inflection point is not the point here.

Comment: Also, what Ryan is saying is to look at the derivative either side and see if it is positive or negative.

Comment: If $f''(x)\geq 0$ for every $x$, then $f$ is convex and so every critical point is a minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'(x)=(x-a)^{2n}(x-b)^{2m+1}$$
So let $\epsilon>0$, then $$f'(b+\epsilon)=(b-a+\epsilon)^{2n}(\epsilon)^{2m+1}>0.$$
Instead $$f'(b-\epsilon)=(b-a-\epsilon)^{2n}(-\epsilon)^{2m+1}<0.$$
So if you picture it, you'll see $x=b$ is a minimum.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I was so close. Thanks!